# What's meant here by "concerned"?

Tags: meaning

In "The Song of Flying Fish" by G. K. Chesterton, the author was describing someone saw a figure at the daybreak, saying:

> He saw a figure that might have stepped straight out of the jungle or the bazaar,a figure out of the “Arabian Nights.” The rather ghostly grey twilight which begins to define and yet to discolour everything when the light in the east has ceased to be localized, lifted slowly like a veil of grey gauze and showed him a figure wrapped in outlandish raiment. A scarf of a strange sea-blue, vast and voluminous, went round the head like a turban, and then again round the chin, giving rather the general character of a hood; **so far as the face was concerned** it had all the effects of a mask.

Does "**concerned**" here means "**covered**"?

Comment: What has your research shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"so as far as the face was concerned"

means something like:

"so, just talking for the moment about the face,"

which should help to explain its usage here.